# why does the len function return 2 on some iterations when they are all the same length?

Tags: python

```
from datetime import date

score_list = [
{ 2:date(2018,10,20), 5:date(2018,11,8), 0:date(2018,12,25),},
{ 3:date(2018,10,20), 1:date(2018,11,8), 4:date(2018,12,25),},
{ 0:date(2018,10,20), 1:date(2018,11,8), 0:date(2018,12,25),},
{ 2:date(2018,10,20), 7:date(2018,11,8), 3:date(2018,12,25),},
{ 0:date(2018,10,20), 0:date(2018,11,8), 6:date(2018,12,25),},
]

total = []
ave_total = []
ite=0

for i in score_list:
    sum = 0
    for key in i:
        sum+= key
    total.append(sum) 

print (total)

for j in total:
    **t = len(score_list[ite])
    ave = j/t
    print (t)**
    print (ite)
    ite += 1
    ave_total.append(ave) 
    print (ave)

print (ave_total)
```

while trying to use print to debug what went wrong i noticed that sometimes t returns as 2 while they are all the same length(3).

Comment: What does `**t` mean? If that's intended for highlighting, it doesn't work in code blocks.

Comment: You have duplicate keys.

Comment: You would notice this if you printed `score_list[ite]` instead of just printing the length.

Answer (score 3):

Keys in a dictionary are unique, you have no choice in that.  So, for example:

```
{ 0:date(2018,10,20), 1:date(2018,11,8), 0:date(2018,12,25),},
```

only gives **2** keys because `0` is repeated.

EDIT:
You need to restructure your data, since you will loose any duplicates in the way it is defined right now.  There are several ways around this, here is one:

```
from datetime import date

score_list = [
{ 2:date(2018,10,20), 5:date(2018,11,8), 0:date(2018,12,25),},

{ 3:date(2018,10,20), 1:date(2018,11,8), 4:date(2018,12,25),},

#{ 0:date(2018,10,20), 1:date(2018,11,8), 0:date(2018,12,25),},
{ 0:[date(2018,10,20), date(2018,12,25)], 1:date(2018,11,8), },

{ 2:date(2018,10,20), 7:date(2018,11,8), 3:date(2018,12,25),},

#{ 0:date(2018,10,20), 0:date(2018,11,8), 6:date(2018,12,25),},
{ 0:[date(2018,10,20), date(2018,11,8)], 6:date(2018,12,25),},
]
```

This makes the keys with duplicate values use a `list`.

That means your simple `len()` is no longer adequate:

```
total = []
ave_total = []
ite = 0


for i in score_list:

    sum = 0

    for key in i:
        sum += key

    total.append(sum)

print(total)

for j in total:

    t = 0
    for val in score_list[ite].values():
        if isinstance(val, list):
            t += len(val)
        else:
            t += 1

    #t = len(score_list[ite])

    ave = j/t

    ite += 1

    ave_total.append(ave)

    print (ave)

print (ave_total)
```

You could simplify this if you created every value as a list.

Comment: thanks a lot. is there anyway I can make it to count as 3?